# Ionic cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.wakeUp() method not waking up the phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

For an Ionic 4 app, I am using the method `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.wakeUp()` of the `cordova-plugin-background-mode` along with my bluetooth functionality to wake the screen on any state change of the bluetooth device. It is working on some devices for example its working fine on my Moto phone but not with LG G6.

Is some phones designed to stop screen wake up or is there any settings to change that? I am particularly looking for the settings in an LG G6 device at the moment.

Can users prevent the app from waking the screen when an app is using `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.wakeUp()` method? If so, where can I find the settings to disable them.